# in MySQL, ORDER BY index only used when I include a where on a different field

Tags: mysql, index

Good day,

I have the following query to show products with details.

```
SELECT products.id, userid, slug, city, products.updated_at,
       (SELECT group_concat(categories.name)
             from categories join category_user
                on categories.id = category_user.category_id
             WHERE category_user.user_id = userid) as list
FROM products join 
    (SELECT users.id as userid , files.slug as slug, locations.city
   FROM users left join files on users.file_id = files.id
   left join locations on users.location_id = locations.id
   ) as users_and_products 
on products.creator_id = users_and_products.userid
ORDER BY products.updated_at DESC
LIMIT 50
```

So we show the 50 most recent products with some details, such as a comma separated list of tags.
There is an index on the field products.updated_at. This query takes 754ms on a database of 16000 products.

If I tell the query to USE INDEX, it is 32 ms. I was wondering why the index is not detected automatically?

Additionally, which i think is the strangest part, is that if I add WHERE products.id > 0, the index IS detected and the query is fast. How does adding this where clause help the DB know which index to use?

Thanks and good day,

Dries

Comment: Is the index used if you change the `FROM products join ..` to `FROM products LEFT join ..`?

Comment: Yes it is! But updated_at is a non nullable field. Is the difference that the left join means the database can be certain of all products that will be included with the field? That would also explain why products.id > 0 works

Comment: The (left or inner) join is on `products.creator_id`. Is that nullable? The left option may alter the query results if that column is nullable. If it's not nullable and there is a froeign key from that to `users (id)`, then the queries are equivalent (but MySQL's optimizer is not that bright to make such a transformation)

Comment: Ah it is a nullable field, even though it is never null. An oversight when creating the database.